# Unable to start activity android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there a lot of answers for this question relatively, but none of them can help me resolve my problem, so I start a new one.
I just finish writing code of my project, when I run the project and then a lot of errors came up in the logcat, haven't see these errors before , please help me fix this, thanks in advance.
 Errors were given below.
Errors:(3 major errors in total)
First

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Second

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Third

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Here is a [link](http://sharetext.co/s/4462) that contains the full information.

Comment: that link will eventually disappear so your question and answers will be useless.. Write here at least part of code so people have a clue what is going on.. If u have troubles reformatting somebody else can correct that for you later..Basically the most useful would be view definition in xml layout of mainActivity that contains line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have at least two problems:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at android.util.ArrayMap.indexOf(ArrayMap.java:104)
at android.util.ArrayMap.indexOfKey(ArrayMap.java:336)
at android.util.ArrayMap.get(ArrayMap.java:378)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:916)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:169)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.util.SettingsUtils.getString(SettingsUtils.java:76)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.util.SettingsUtils.getString(SettingsUtils.java:77)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.util.SettingsUtils.getString(SettingsUtils.java:77)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.util.SettingsUtils.getString(SettingsUtils.java:77)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.util.SettingsUtils.getString(SettingsUtils.java:77)
```

Your `SettingsUtils` class has a `getString()` that is calling itself.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
at me.knoxc.fdemo.fragment.SwipeRefreshListFragment.onViewCreated(SwipeRefreshListFragment.java:42)
```

`SwipeRefreshListFragment` has an `onCreateView()` method that is returning its own layout, where the widget in that layout with `android:id` of `@android:id/list` is not a `ListView`.

Comment: The first problem you said still unfix after I change the return value to a SharedPreference object, or you can see it in this link http://sharetext.co/s/4472 , about the second problem you said, I did cast the Layout into ListView, beside I don't exactly know how to fix it by the way you saying, or you can see it in this link http://sharetext.co/s/4474 , thanks for comment.

Comment: I have now solved the SettingsUtils's problem, Others still remain unfix.